# Обновление отображение картинки загруженной через file upload

Tags: php, upload

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть код который загружает файл и перезаписывает его.

```
<?php
$uploaddir = '/home/uploads/contacts/';
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['userfile']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir . $_POST['file_name'] . '.jpg'))
{
    print "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.";
} else {
    print "There some errors!";
}
?>
```

Но на сайте эта картинка отображается только после ctrl+f5. Обычное обновление не помогает. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: кешируется она. в этом проблема

Comment: @n.osennij этот кеш отключать на стороне хостинга или на стороне самого сайта?

Comment: это в браузере у каждого пользователя

Comment: @n.osennij не может быть, должно быть кеширование не в браузере

Comment: Вы спросили в чём дело. вам ответили. Открою вам тайну - браузеры. кешируют. файлы. Ужас какой, правда? А гугл хром - тот ещё засранец.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Файлы кешируются браузером.

Сейчас вы спросите, а как быть, хоть в вопросе этого и нет. По нормальному имя файла на сервере - уникальный набор символов. Например, `ddda671995a17b8746068d807490e9b3.jpg`. Обновляете картинку - меняете её имя. Ну и всё. Проблема решена.

Ещё вариант - добавлять к имени файла переменную, которая говорит о версии этого файла. Можно, например, добавлять время поледнего обновления файла, тогда не придётся менять имя файла, если его имя - важно.

```
<img src="/some_url/my_image.jpg?TIMESTAMP">
```

В примере выше после знака вопроса добавляется что-нибудь, что поможет браузеру понять - старый это файл (и его можно брать из кеша) или новый (нужно загрузить по новой).